# Call calendar with certain options on range doubleclick

Tags: excel, vba

I am calling calendar form on range double click, however there are possibilities to add more options to calendar form. I am currently calling calendar by this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Target.Offset(1, 0)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7:C90")) Is Nothing Then datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable = 0 Then
        rng.Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Target.Value = datevariable
        rng.Select
    End If

End Sub
```

It opens very basic calendar. I have more advanced calendar by using this code:

```
Sub AdvancedCalendarTimeschedule()

    Dim datevariable

    On Error Resume Next

    datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate( _
        SelectedDate:=Range("'OtherData'!P17").Value, _
        FirstDayOfWeek:=Monday, _
        DateFontSize:=12, _
        TodayButton:=True, _
        OkayButton:=True, _
        ShowWeekNumbers:=True, _
        BackgroundColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
        HeaderColor:=RGB(128, 128, 128), _
        HeaderFontColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
        SubHeaderColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
        SubHeaderFontColor:=RGB(56, 56, 56), _
        DateColor:=RGB(247, 247, 247), _
        DateFontColor:=RGB(56, 56, 56), _
        TrailingMonthFontColor:=RGB(155, 194, 230), _
        DateHoverColor:=RGB(90, 195, 126), _
        DateSelectedColor:=RGB(216, 216, 216), _
        SaturdayFontColor:=RGB(201, 0, 0), _
        SundayFontColor:=RGB(201, 0, 0), _
        TodayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 80))
    If datevariable <> 0 Then Range("'OtherData'!P17") = datevariable

End Sub
```

`Range("'OtherData'!P17")` should be `ActiveCell`. How to make double click appear advanced calendar above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Sub AdvancedCalendarTimeschedule()
> ```

Make that a function that returns a `Date`:

```
Private Function AdvancedCalendarTimeschedule() As Date
```

Remove the local `datevariable` declaration, you don't need it; make the function return the selected date instead of writing it to a cell:

```
AdvancedCalendarTimeSchedule = CalendarForm.GetDate( _
    SelectedDate:=Range("'OtherData'!P17").Value, _
    FirstDayOfWeek:=Monday, _
    DateFontSize:=12, _
    TodayButton:=True, _
    OkayButton:=True, _
    ShowWeekNumbers:=True, _
    BackgroundColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
    HeaderColor:=RGB(128, 128, 128), _
    HeaderFontColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
    SubHeaderColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
    SubHeaderFontColor:=RGB(56, 56, 56), _
    DateColor:=RGB(247, 247, 247), _
    DateFontColor:=RGB(56, 56, 56), _
    TrailingMonthFontColor:=RGB(155, 194, 230), _
    DateHoverColor:=RGB(90, 195, 126), _
    DateSelectedColor:=RGB(216, 216, 216), _
    SaturdayFontColor:=RGB(201, 0, 0), _
    SundayFontColor:=RGB(201, 0, 0), _
    TodayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 80))
```

Note that if the user cancels the `CalendarForm` dialog (I presume it's a dialog), then the function will return `0`: this should be accounted for in the calling code. Also note that the `DoubleClick` handler needs to declare the `datevariable` - in your code that variable is out of scope and undeclared. The fact that your code runs at all means you're missing `Option Explicit` at the top of the module - add it, it will force you to consistently declare every variable you ever use, and that is a very good thing to do.

```
Dim datevariable As Date
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7:C90")) Is Nothing Then datevariable = AdvancedCalendarTimeSchedule
```